# One liner for throwing exception if string is null

Tags: c#, exception, web-config

I have some web.config settings that I want to ensure are always present. I want a neat way of doing this, such as creating a field for each setting, and in the field initializer I would somehow throw an exception if the value is null.

My original thought was to use ternary operator `?:` but that would involve writing the same key twice. I don't want to repeat the key name because this makes the code more brittle (should I ever want to rename a key I'd need to do it in 2 places). Is there any way that this duplication could be avoided?

```
public class MyClass
{
    //what I don't really want (won't compile):
    private readonly string _name1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyName"] != null
                                   ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyName"]
                                   : throw new Exception();

    //what I sort of want (won't compile):
    private readonly string _name2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyName"]
                                   ?? throw new Exception();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a little odd, but just to think outside the box you could add some method to your class (or as a static method) like:

```
public string ThrowConfigException(string message)
{
    throw new System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException(message);
}
```

Then, you could add properties to your class that look like this:

```
private string _name1;
public string Name1
{
    get
    {
        return _name1 ?? (_name1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name1"]) ?? ThrowConfigException("Name1 does not exist in the config file");
    }
}
```

Update in C# 7.0: You are able to [throw an exception inline](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/).  The above example could now be written as:

```
private string _name1;
public string Name1
{
    get
    {
        return 
            _name1 ?? 
            (_name1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name1"]) ?? 
            throw new System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException(nameof(Name1) + " does not exist in the config file");
    }
}
```

Comment: I love this, it's brilliant! Closest we can get to a one-liner.

Comment: I'm using it like this: `private readonly string _name2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyName"] ?? ThrowConfigException();`

Comment: But the question stipulated: "But I don't want the repeated call to AppSettings for each key". This will read the key from the AppSettings for each call.

Comment: @DvS True, in which case you could add a private backing property.

Comment: @DvS I meant that I didn't want to have to type the name twice. The call to AppSettings is super quick so performance isn't the issue, repeated code is. Sorry for the confusion, I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: If you only need this inside one method, a function also works.

      Func<string, string> isNull = (parameter) =>
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(parameter);
      };

Answer (score 2):

You could cut down on a lot of duplicate code by separating the logic into a separate (static) method and just calling that for each key you want to test.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly string _name1 = GetConfigValue("MyName");
    private readonly string _name2 = GetConfigValue("AnotherSetting");

    private static string GetConfigValue(string settingName)
    {
        var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingName];

        if (setting == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("The setting {0} is missing.", settingName));

        return setting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep I thought about using a separate method but I was wondering if it could be done without one. Like maybe with some Linq or ConvertTo trickery. Anyway I think I'll probably go with this, thanks.

Comment: If accessing a missing key threw an exception, you'd be all set. :) I get what you're suggesting with the null coalescer, since accessing a missing key returns null, but I can't think of any other way to shorten your code using that fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type to represent your AppSettings and properties with getters, which would read each value once only.

```
public static class Settings
{
    private static string _myName;

    public static string MyName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myName == null)
            {
                _myName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyName"];
            }

            if (_myName == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("AppSetting 'MyName' is not present in the application configuration file.");
            }

            return _myName;
        }
    }
}
```